# File server won't serve files over 32 KB

Tags: http, go, response, swagger-ui, fileserver

I have a go program running in a docker container. I have set it up so that when you go to localhost:8080 (the port that the program is running on) it serves up the documentation files which were created using swagger-ui. The index.html file shows up, and in that file it imports one css file, one png file, and two javascript files. The png gets imported correctly (it is only 628 bytes); however, the other three files don't get served correctly (they are all a few hundred KB). I believe the problem is that they are too big as if I delete part of the files to get them under 32 KB, they are served correctly. I am not sure how to increase this file limit, though.

I've looked through all of my code and a fair amount of the http package to see where this hard limit might be set, but can't find it anywhere.

Here's the code that creates my fileserver and serves the files

```
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir(docRoot)) // docRoot is a config variable
for _, f := range files {
    path := fmt.Sprintf("/%s", f.Name())
    serveFile := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if r.URL.Path == path || r.URL.Path == "/index.html" && path == "/" {
            fs.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        } else {
            origHandler.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        }
    }
    docHandler.HandleFunc(path, serveFile)
}
```

I would think that there would be some Handler.SetMaxSize() or maybe ResponseWriter.SetMaxSize() method, but I can't find anything like this in the http package. Does anyone know how to increase this hard limit or where it might be set?

Comment: There is no size limit. What does the client receive? Does it receive 32K data, or nothing? I've done things like this before, and one thing that always failed was the media type, because the FileServer does not set the Content-Type. Maybe you have a similar problem? Did you try with curl?

Comment: The client receives a 200 response where the size field in the header is set correctly, but there is no data in they body. It looks like the content-type is also set correctly with `text/css; charset=utf-8` for the css and `application/javascript` for the js. However, in the console it also prints an error `net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 200 (OK)` presumably because the content-length is set correctly but the body has a length of zero. I've tried this on Chrome/Safari/Firefox so I don't think the browser is the problem either.

Comment: When I curl for the css file I get `curl: (18) transfer closed with 33002 bytes remaining to read`. 33002 is the length of data that it should be receiving in the body, so this seems like the same error I get in browser.

Comment: Did you try running this outside the docker container? Maybe it'll help diagnose what's wrong with it.

Comment: Interestingly enough, it does return data when I do that, but only the first 32KB of data for each file.

Comment: Are these files served by fs, or origHandler? Maybe there's something wrong with origHandler? Can you add some printfs to see if it is origHandler or fs handling these files?

Comment: It is fs serving these, and when curling with -v it shows that `Curl_http_done: called premature == 1`, which sounds like something on the server side closed the connection unexpectedly.

Comment: I'm out of suggestions... Try serving the files with a small handler yourself?

Comment: Yeah I'll try that. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out the problem and it turned out to have nothing to do with the function itself, just where I was calling it. I was calling it in a function to create a gateway proxy, and was modifying the handler afterwards to add other stuff such as metrics reporting. I just had to make the call to add this stuff the last call of the parent function, and it works now.